# How do I make a pop-up window with choices in python?

Tags: python, interactive

For a project I am working on, I want to make a pop-up window with several different choices, that can return a value based on which choice the user picks; I found solutions to get simple pop-ups, but not ones that return a value. I am using Python 3.8.

Comment: Have you looked at [TKinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html)?

Comment: there are many *ways*, what are you looking for specifically, and examples to show in detail?

Comment: I have, but I only found an option for a simple pop-up. I am fairly inexperienced, so I might have missed something. Thank you.

Comment: I remember a few years ago coding a program where there was a big window with a text box and then a list of options that comes up, and the user can select one of the options which returns a value and continues the program.

Comment: There are some predefined options in [`tkinter.messagebox`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/tkinter.messagebox.html), otherwise you will need to craft the dialog yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Comment: PySimpleGui couldn’t make it easier to create a simple gui dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As barny suggested, PySimpleGUI is about as easy as it gets.

What you've described is what's called a [one-shot window](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/#recipe-pattern-1b-one-shot-window-self-closing-single-line) in the PySimpleGUI Cookbook.

These types of GUIs can be written as a single line of PySimpleGUI code because you don't need a full event loop.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

event, values = sg.Window('Choose an option', [[sg.Text('Select one->'), sg.Listbox(['Option a', 'Option b', 'Option c'], size=(20, 3), key='LB')],
    [sg.Button('Ok'), sg.Button('Cancel')]]).read(close=True)

if event == 'Ok':
    sg.popup(f'You chose {values["LB"][0]}')
else:
    sg.popup_cancel('User aborted')
```

After the call to Window, with the chained `read` call, you're provided the event used to close the window (which button or if closed with the "X") and the dictionary of values.  In this case, your values dictionary will have a single item `values['LB']`.  For Listboxes, this value will be a list.  To get the item chosen, you could reference `values['LB'][0]`

Answer (score 1):

PySimpleGui is the way to go for simplicity - and it seems to work with Python 3.8.3 on Windows 10.

Creating a simple gui dialog to make a selection can't get much easier than this (although it can also do much more complex UI when needed):

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

#sg.theme('DarkAmber')   # Add a touch of color

options = ['Option a','Option b','Option c']

# All the stuff inside your window.
layout = [ 
            [sg.Text('Select one->'), sg.Listbox(options,select_mode=sg.LISTBOX_SELECT_MODE_SINGLE,size=(20,len(options)))],
            [sg.Button('Ok'), sg.Button('Cancel')]
        ]

# Create the Window
window = sg.Window('Make your choice', layout)

# Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the input
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print( f"event={event}" )
    if event is None or event == 'Ok' or event == 'Cancel': # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
        
# close  the window        
window.close()

if event == "Cancel":
    print( "You cancelled" )
else:
    print('You entered ', values[0])
    sg.popup( f"You selected {values[0]}" )
```

Comment: You will want to add a check for event == sg.WIN_CLOSED in case the user closes the window using the "X".  Otherwise you'll remain in the event loop forever when the "X" is used.

Comment: Thanks - oddly the original source I copied included that test but it gives an error that WIN_CLOSED isn't defined :-o so I removed it, but obviously never checked hitting the X. I've added a test for `event is None` which seems to be what I get. Just updated from PySimpleGui 4.18.2 to 4.20.0 and it's just the same.